# How do you delete an axis when plotting data using Datura?

Tags: python, visualization

Using [Datura](https://datura.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html), how do you prevent an axis from appearing in the figure?

if you try y_ticks=None, a y-axis still appears:

```
datura.plot([1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 1], y_ticks=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you include a list of length 1 for x_ticks or y_ticks, no axis will be drawn for the respective axis.

```
datura.plot([1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 1], x_ticks=[1, 2, 3], y_ticks=[2], y_label="no axis!")
```

(Note, however, that if you choose a value outside of the domain or range of the data in the figure, the axis will be extended to include that data point. This behavior can be useful in the event that you want to extend the axis without drawing it.)

[image]